Set a different tax rate for specific products and user role in WooCommerce
I have a problem with WooCommerce taxes.
I need to add a new 8% tax before the total price to certain products only for a specific role, 'different_user'.
Other products already include other taxes that are shown before the final price, and then added to it.
I use a plugin for wholesalers (Wholesale Suite) that sets a default tax to this type of customers ('different_user'). So, in order for the rest of the users not to receive taxes, I must have the taxes disabled in the tab of each of the products:
Tax status ............................ None
Tax class .................................. (any)
I have also created a tax option with a zero amount
Tax status ............................ Taxable
Tax class ................................ zero rate
In any case, taxes are only received by wholesale users, so I need a way to add this tax to certain products and users with the role of 'different_user'.
Is there a way to disable taxes for certain user roles?
Maybe it would be better to disable taxes for all roles except the 'different_user' role, and create different tax rates in the WooCommerce settings
What would be the best option?
Is there a way to disable taxes for certain user roles?
It is important that this tax does not affect any other taxes or discounts already added to WooCommerce.
<tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-impuesto-1">
<th>Impuesto</th>
<td data-title="Impuesto">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">2,20
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
 </span>
 </td>
</tr>

I have managed to add the tax to the products I need using add_action through their "ID", and it works.
But it is shown on a different line:
<tr class="fee">
<th>Ajuste de impuestos adicionales</th>
<td data-title="Ajuste de impuestos adicionales">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<bdi>0,38<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
</bdi>
</span>
</td>
</tr>

How should I make this tax be added to the ones I already have from WooCommerce, instead of being shown on a new line?
I have tried several times, but I am really confused about this, I cannot understand how WooCommerce works with taxes.
I could directly add a new tax rate in WooCommerce, but since it is only for certain products, I cannot do it and I am blocked
This is the result:

// Hook to modify taxes based on products and user roles
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_tax_to_selected_products', 20, 1);

function add_custom_tax_to_selected_products($cart) {
    // Check if it is admin or AJAX request, and avoid executing the code in that case
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the user has the role 'different_user'
    if (!current_user_can('usuario_diferente')) {
        return;
    }

    // IDs of products that should receive the 8% tax
    $product_ids_with_tax = array(355, 625); 

    // Variable to store the total additional tax
    $tax_amount = 0;

    //Iterate over the products in the cart
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is on the list of products with additional tax
        if (in_array($product_id, $product_ids_with_tax)) {
            //Calculate 8% of the subtotal of this product
            $item_total = $cart_item['line_total']; // Total price of the product in the cart without taxes
            $tax_amount += ($item_total * 0.08);    // Add 8% of the total price of that product
        }
    }

     // If there is a tax amount to add, we add it to the total taxes
    if ($tax_amount > 0) {
         
        $cart->add_fee( __('Ajuste de impuestos adicionales', 'woocommerce'), $tax_amount, true, '' );
    } 
}

/////////// EDIT THE QUERY:
EDIT THE QUERY:
This is a possible solution, but I'm not sure.
I tested it in a test environment, and it works, but I don't know if it will be compatible with other discounts and taxes that I have on the website.
I hope you can help me.
This is the possible solution:
// Hook to modify taxes based on products and user roles
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_tax_to_selected_products', 20, 1);

function add_custom_tax_to_selected_products($cart) {
    // Check if it is admin or AJAX request, and avoid executing the code in that case
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the user has the 'usuario_diferente' role
    if (!current_user_can('usuario_diferente')) {
        return;
    }

    // IDs of products that should receive the 8% tax
    $product_ids_with_tax = array(966, 301, 328, 326, 327, 355, 625); // Sustituir con los IDs reales de los productos

    // Variable to store the total additional tax
    $tax_amount = 0;

    // Iterate over the products in the cart
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is on the list of products with additional tax
        if (in_array($product_id, $product_ids_with_tax)) {
            // Calculate 8% of the subtotal of this product
            $item_total = $cart_item['line_total']; // Total price of the product in the cart without taxes
            $tax_amount += ($item_total * 0.08);    // Add 8% of the total price of that product
        }
    }

    // Si hay un monto de impuesto a agregar, o no hay otros impuestos presentes
    if ($tax_amount > 0) {
        // Get current taxes
        $taxes = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_taxes();

        // If taxes already exist, add the additional tax
        if (!empty($taxes)) {
            foreach ($taxes as $key => $value) {
                $taxes[$key] += $tax_amount;
                break; // We only modified the first tax found
            }
        } else {
            // If there is no tax, we add the tax as the first one
            $cart->add_fee(__('Impuesto', 'woocommerce'), $tax_amount, true); // Lo marcamos como impuesto
        }

        // Set modified taxes if there were already taxes
        if (!empty($taxes)) {
            WC()->cart->set_cart_contents_taxes($taxes);
        }
    }
}


I'm sorry for not stating all this from the beginning, I didn't think it was important. I just figured it out when I saw that your options weren't working. I'm really sorry for the time you spent on this question and I'm embarrassed about it. I edited the question, but I understand that you no longer like it. I'm sorry, I understand that this was a very important mistake on my part. Thank you for your time and dedication @LoicTheAztec . Even if I didn't manage to solve the problem for which I came here, at least I learned a lesson that will serve me in more facets of life.

The thing is not about if I like it or not, it's about, understanding processes, good practices and clarity. For example, the hook woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees is exclusively made to add fees. To alter cart items, you can use woocommerce_before_calculate_totals. For cart contents taxes, you should use woocommerce_cart_get_cart_contents_taxes composite filter hook.

Thank you, I'll see if I can find the correct way to do it by tomorrow. Perhaps the most logical thing would be to disable taxes for all roles except the ones I'm interested in, and then add taxes and activate them for each product that requires them. I don't know, I don't have much time to figure everything out. You've been very kind, I'm sorry I confused you with my meaningless comments.
